# Component of an Open Set: Polygonal Arcs

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

So I'm reading my Complex Analysis book, and I'm a little confused.
Specifically, I'm puzzled by why it is that we need an open disk that does not intersect any of the line segments of the polygonal arc except those with $z$ as one of its end points. Additionally, couldn't there be other paths through $U$ that intersect some point in this disk that shares no other points besides $z_0$ in common with the first path?
Given that $U$ is an open set, it is straightforward enough that there exists an $r$ that does not intersect any of these line segments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, a *polygonal arc* is not allowed to have self-intersections. So, to be able to say

> the polygonal arc in $U$ formed when the segment from $z$ to $w$ is appended to $A$,

we have to know that this segment from $z$ to $w$ does not cross line segments already in $A$. This is the reason for the choice of $U$.

> couldn't there be other paths

Sure there are. Not every step of proof is dictated by necessity; there are choices to be made. The author needed *some* polygonal arc going to $w$, and
this was the construction  of such an arc they chose to present.